# Get Percentage of All Columns by Column Total

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Label       Jan       Feb       Mar
    A         1         2         3
    B         1         4         9
    C         1         4         3
```

The number of columns after "Label" will continue to increase month over month.

I want to create an output that looks like this:

```
Label       Jan       Feb       Mar
    A      0.33      0.20      0.20
    B      0.33      0.40      0.40
    C      0.33      0.40      0.20
```

Below works but removes the label. I can cbind the label back but wondering if there is an easier way

```
library(dplyr)
df[,-1] %>%
  mutate_all(funs(./sum(.))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at/mutate_if` or `mutate` with `across` (from `dplyr` version `>= 1.00`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
     mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ ./sum(.)))
```

---

if we use an older `dplyr` version `< 1.00`

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ./sum(.))
```

---

If we need percentage, we can use `formattable::percent` which would enable it to remain as a numeric column (in case we want to do color scaling on those columns)

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ 
           formattable::percent(./sum(.))))
```

-output

```
# Label    Jan    Feb    Mar
#1     A 33.33% 20.00% 20.00%
#2     B 33.33% 40.00% 60.00%
#3     C 33.33% 40.00% 20.00%
```

#### data

```
df - structure(list(Label = c("A", "B", "C"), Jan = c(1L, 1L, 1L), 
    Feb = c(2L, 4L, 4L), Mar = c(3L, 9L, 3L)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: One more question which is an add on but how do I make all these values percentage format. I can ask in a separate question too.

Comment: It does, I can in 7 min :)

Comment: no luck with that: 
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  Unsupported type for SparkDataFrame: formattablenumeric

Comment: results_percentage_format <- results %>%
    mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ 
           formattable::percent(./sum(.))))

Comment: @nak5120 Ok, then may be you need `paste0(100 * ./sum(.), "%")`